# Joining two datasets without knowledge of keys

Tags: dataset

Which technique should I use to attempt to find common simple keys between two datasets in order to join them, without any knowledge of neither the column-names, nor which columns are key-columns.

Let's say I have these datasets:

**Dataset A**:

| [Col 1] | [Col 2] | [Col 3] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Z |
| A | 3 | X |
| C | 2 | W |
| C | 4 | Y |

**Dataset B**:

| [Col 1] | [Col 2] | [Col 3] | [Col 4] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2022-01-02 | 2 | 0.1 |
| B | 2022-01-03 | 3 | 0.12 |
| C | 2022-01-04 | 1 | 0.54 |
| C | 2022-01-05 | 4 | 0.91 |
| C | 2022-01-06 | 5 | 0.01 |

I would like to establish, that `(Dataset A::\[Col 2] right join Dataset B::\[Col 3])` is the most probable join between the two datasets.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: What language? Are there any keys at all (so do you know this) or is it possible that there are no or multiple keys.

Comment: The language is irrelevant. I'm looking for a technique.
It is possible that each dataset could be thought of as having several keys. 
I'm looking for the most probably simple key-pair (I.e., I'm not interested in the possibility of composite keys)

Comment: To expand a bit, I might want to - for example - rank all possible simple key-pairs according to some probability measure, and then pick the key-pair with the highest probability. It's Ok, that the key-pair with the highest probability is a "terrible" choice - so to speak - it's still the most probable.